Form Not Updating with Correct Model Value After Postback
I’m working on an ASP.NET Core 8 project where I have an AddOrUpdate method to either add a new entry or update an existing one. However, after submitting the form and successfully saving the data, the hidden input field for the Id is not displaying the updated value, even though the result.Data.Id is greater than 0.
Here's my code:
public async Task<IActionResult> AddOrUpdate(int id = 0)
{
    AddOrUpdateDTO model;

    if (id > 0)
    {
        model = await _blogService.GetById(id);
    }
    else
    {
        model = new();
    }

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddOrUpdate(AddOrUpdateDTO model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        GenericResultDTO<AddOrUpdateDTO> result = await _blogService.AddOrUpdate(model, User.GetUserId());

        if (!result.IsSuccessful)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", result.ResultMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["Result"] = "Saved successfully";

            // I expect this to update the form with the new Id value
            return await AddOrUpdate(result.Data.Id);
        }
    }

    return View(model);
}

In my view, I have a hidden input for the Id:
<input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />

When the form is submitted and the record is saved, result.Data.Id contains the correct value (greater than 0). However, when the form is rendered again, the Id in the hidden input field is still 0.
I'm sure that the model is being updated properly after the postback. What could be causing the hidden input field to not update with the correct Id?
What I've tried:

Verified that result.Data.Id has the correct value after saving.

Tried directly returning the updated model after saving in the POST action:
 return View(result.Data);



But the Id in the form is still not updating.
Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Conclusion first, you can clear the ModelState in several ways to solve this.
Modify your return method
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddOrUpdate(AddOrUpdateDTO model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        GenericResultDTO<AddOrUpdateDTO> result = await _blogService.AddOrUpdate(model, "UserId");

        if (!result.IsSuccessful)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", result.ResultMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["Result"] = "Saved successfully";

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(AddOrUpdate), new { id = result.Data.Id });
        }
    }

    return View(model);
}


Explanation
When using Tag-Helper, there is something to pay attention to in document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-8.0#the-input-tag-helper :

When ASP.NET Core MVC calculates the value of ModelExpression, it
inspects several sources, including ModelState. Consider . The calculated value attribute is the
first non-null value from:
ModelState entry with key "Name".
Result of the expression Model.Name.

Which means when rendering the page, the value from ModelState is chosen first.
Now as we can see in your code, in my sample project locally, when you submit the form, it returns the method of AddOrUpdate. Even if the model is popped up correctly,

The ModelState ,added by me to show the value, contains the Id of different value.

It is still 0 , and thus after rendering the page, the hidden value in your page is still 0. This explains why the id not updated in your project.

Additional
Model and ModelState are separated when updating in data-protection, experience, validation and others. Since you send no new request, the Id is from the hidden input and not updated. And other properties are updated as the form is submitted.
